# Best way to monitor uptime of a remote windows server?

Tags: uptime

The company I work with currently has 10 windows boxes running various in house scripts, however occasionally one goes down and no one notices for periods of up to 24 hours because the data that is manufactured is only gathered on weekly intervals.  Does anyone know of a management system that will notify when a box goes down and possibly shoot uptime and response statistics back to a web management system on a linux box?

Answer (score 5):

There are many.

I use [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) for monitoring Windows and Linux servers.  You might also look into [Zenoss](http://www.zenoss.com/).  Both are open source.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.pingdom.com/ is simple to use and you get a 30 day trial - 9.95 a month gets you a lot if you decide to sign on.  have it for all my apps

Answer (score 0):

I would have a bash script call ping on the machines and email me (or whomever is responsible) when a box goes down.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen [IPMonitor](http://www.solarwinds.com/products/ipmonitor/) in use, and it is a very good tool (but expensive).  [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) is a free alternative, and it's supposed to be quite good, but I've never used it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I know [nmap](http://nmap.org/) has a way of showing you the machine's uptime when you use the OS fingerprinting option.