# How to get Windows load average with PHP?

Tags: php, wmi

i would like to show the load average of my windows server through a php website..

How can i do ?  is there a port of uptime on windows ? how can i call the right WMI call from php ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load Average in PHP on Windows :

```
<?php
     echo system('typeperf "\Processor(*)\% Processor Time"');
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe [this](http://www.4webhelp.net/scripts/php/uptime.php) is it what you looking for? Or atleast a answer on your windows uptime question.

**EDIT:**

Or you find something more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615664/best-way-to-monitor-uptime-of-a-remote-windows-server), just suggest you something.

**EDIT:**

A suggestion for your average load time : [`sys_getloadavg`](http://www.phpbuilder.com/manual/function.sys-getloadavg.php)

Comment: sorry sysgetloadavg is not available on windows.. and what i need from uptime is not the real uptime of the machine but the load averages ..